# Overcoming lack of inheritance in rust

Tags: inheritance, rust

I have a third party class that I normally in C++ would extend to get my own specialized type.
How to do it in Rust? The reason I'm trying to do it that I of course could use composition instead but by doing so I cannot easily call the methods from the 3rd party type.
How is it done in Rust?
**[Edit]**

```
use some_3rd_crate;
struct MyStruct{third_type: some_3rd_crate::Type,}
```

How to get all the public methods of some_3rd_crate::Type into scope of my type so I can use them like:

```
let mt = MyStruct{third_type: some_3rd_crate::Type()};
mt.call_3rd_party_function();
```

Comment: This is far too broad a question to be answerable. Though [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html) certainly cover much of the design space that inheritance in C++ is used for.

Comment: Could you post an specific example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement [`AsRef`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsRef.html) or [`AsMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.AsMut.html) for your type:

```rust
impl AsRef<some_3rd_crate::Type> for MyStruct
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &some_3rd_crate::Type {
        &self.third_type
    }
}
```

Then could be used as:

```rust
let mt = MyStruct{third_type: some_3rd_crate::Type()};
mt.as_ref().call_3rd_party_function();
```